# Pattern interference in rewriterules in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have trouble with a pattern interference when defining rewriterules in .htaccess.

The website links I am trying to rewrite are:

- example.com/?item=work --> example.com/work
- example.com/?item=work&tile=x --> example.com/work/x
- example.com/?item=travel --> example.com/travel
- example.com/?item=travel&blog=x --> example.com/travel/x
- example.com/?item=about --> example.com/about

I have used the [online rewrite rule generator](http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php) as my knowledge is very limited here. For the rewrite rules for the "tile" and "blog" URL I have added the "work" and "travel" respectively in the pattern to make them unique. For the general pages "work","travel" and "about" I cannot apply the same logic as there is nothing left before the slash (can I somehow include the full URL as a pattern?). Thus, it interferes with the other two rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?item=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^travel/([^/]*)$ ?item=travel&blog=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^work/([^/]*)$ /?item=work&tile=$1 [L]
```

I have tried to do some research and found that I can include an additional criteria to specify it is an item:

```
RewriteRule ^item/([^/]*)$ /?item=$1 [L]
```

But is there also a way to write the rule(s) in such a way that this is not needed and using "example.com/about" will simply redirect you to "example.com/?item=about" without interfering with the other two rules?

**Edit**

I was just thinking under the shower that I can use "work", "about" and "travel" as patterns themselves. This results in the below set of rules and they actually work (if they are in the right order) :-)

```
RewriteRule ^travel/([^/]*)$ ?item=travel&blog=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^work/([^/]*)$ /?item=work&tile=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^about /?item=about [L]
RewriteRule ^travel /?item=travel [L]
RewriteRule ^work /?item=work [L]
```

However, this looks quite dirty. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks good. To improve it, the last three can be replaced with:

```
RewriteRule ^(about|travel|work)$ /?item=$1 [L]
```

The other two need to stay the same because the parameters are named differently so can't be done in one rule.

Comment: Thanks, this makes it more clean and works :-)

I have one related question; the rewrite rules work perfectly on the server. But trying to run the website locally with XAMPP (Apache) continuously routes it back to "http://localhost/dashboard/". It looks like it cannot find the URL? I have tried to use RewriteBase, but this doesn't help. Also looked up how Apache needs to be configured and I made sure AllowOverride is set to All. Would you know how I could get these rewrite rules to work locally via XAMPP?

Comment: You're welcome, glad it's better for you. I suggest opening a new question about this other problem you have. Needs looking at properly.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help! I will open a new question.