# .htaccess rewrite rules do not work locally with XAMPP

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, xampp

I have been able to successfully create rewrite rules in .htaccess to rationalize the URL's of my website (thanks to [SuperDuperApps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41623568/pattern-interference-in-rewriterules-in-htaccess/41625173?noredirect=1#comment70526221_41625173) as well):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^travel/([^/]*)$ ?item=travel&blog=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^work/([^/]*)$ /?item=work&tile=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(about|travel|work)$ /?item=$1 [L]
```

This works perfect when I access the website online via the server. However, when running it locally via XAMPP I am continuously routed back to "*localhost/dashboard/*" (instead of "*localhost/example/travel*" --> "*localhost/example/?item=travel*" for example).

I have set *AllowOverride* to *All* and tried to include *RewriteBase*, but I am not getting it to work.

Does anybody know how to successfully configure/setup XAMPP or enhance the rewrite rules in such a way that it does work locally with XAMPP as well?

Comment: I assume that you use a different path in your local development setup, compared to your production system. If so, then the issue is that you are rewriting to an _absolute_ path (leading slash (`/`) in your path) which will make the browser send a request to a resource relative from your http servers root. So instead either use _relative_ paths in your targets. Alternatively you can also create full absolute paths or URLs, but then you need some conditional in your rules to inject the local path in your targets.

Comment: Hi Arkascha, thank you for your reply. I have tried including the absolute path <base href="http://localhost/example/"> in the html page (just as I have <base href="http://example.com/"> included now for the website running in production). But this does not fix the problem. Thus, I would like to go for the relative option you suggest. With the leading slash you are referring to the rewrite rules? Do you know how I make the rewrite rules relative?

Comment: Well.... by _removing_ the leading slash??? I am not really sure if you understand the difference between a relative and an absolute path... And also... Neither `localhost/example/` or `example.com/` are valid URLs or absolut paths. `/example/` would be an absolute path, `https://example.com/` would be a valid URL.